# How to draw image dynamically on a canvas line between two cells

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, canvas

I know how to draw line using `<canvas>` tags.
I want to draw ladder one canvas line I created.
It should be dynamically because the line's angle change everytime so manual solution to copy \ paste picture of a ladder with specific angle won't help me.

This is what I have:
[image]

This is what I **want**:
[image]

I tried to use:

```
      var imageObj = new Image();

      imageObj.onload = function() {
        context.drawImage(imageObj, 120, 50);
      };
      imageObj.src = 'http://s28.postimg.org/7sjqjzpah/ladderpattern.png';
```

but it print me only one small part of the ladder.
Any idea how can I make every line being created to appear as a ladder?

[DEMO (JSFIDDLE): Board with only lines (without ladders)](http://jsfiddle.net/hrLo5a3b/3/)
[DEMO (JSFIDDLE): With picture I tried to draw](http://jsfiddle.net/hrLo5a3b/4/)

**CSS:**

```
td {
    width: 100px;
    height: 90px;
    text-align: left;
    vertical-align: top;
    border: 1px solid black;
    position: relative;
}
table
{
    position: fixed;
    left:9px;
    top:8px;
}

tr:nth-child(even) td:nth-child(odd), tr:nth-child(odd) td:nth-child(even)
{
    background:#00A2E8;
}

td span {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
}

#myCanvas {
    z-index: 10;
    position:absolute;
    font:bold;
    color:red;

}
```

**HTML:**

```
<body>

<div id="board" value="5">
<canvas id="myCanvas" width="600" height="500"></canvas>
<canvas id="myCanvas2" width="600" height="500"></canvas>
<table oncontextmenu="return false">
   <tbody>
    <tr>
     <td class="" cellnumber="21" row="4" col="0"><span>21</span></td>
     <td class="" cellnumber="22" row="4" col="1"><span>22</span></td>
     <td class="" cellnumber="23" row="4" col="2"><span>23</span></td>
     <td class="" cellnumber="24" row="4" col="3"><span>24</span></td>
     <td class="" cellnumber="25" row="4" col="4"><span>25</span></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
     <td class="" cellnumber="16" row="3" col="0"><span>16</span></td>
     <td class="" cellnumber="17" row="3" col="1"><span>17</span></td>
     <td class="" cellnumber="18" row="3" col="2"><span>18</span></td>
     <td class="" cellnumber="19" row="3" col="3"><span>19</span></td>
     <td class="" cellnumber="20" row="3" col="4"><span>20</span></td></tr>
    <tr>
     <td class="" cellnumber="11" row="2" col="0"><span>11</span></td>
     <td class="" cellnumber="12" row="2" col="1"><span>12</span></td>
     <td class="" cellnumber="13" row="2" col="2"><span>13</span></td>
     <td class="" cellnumber="14" row="2" col="3"><span>14</span></td>
     <td class="" cellnumber="15" row="2" col="4"><span>15</span> </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
     <td class="" cellnumber="6" row="1" col="0"><span>6</span></td>
     <td class="" cellnumber="7" row="1" col="1"><span>7</span></td>
     <td class="" cellnumber="8" row="1" col="2"><span>8</span></td>
     <td class="" cellnumber="9" row="1" col="3"><span>9</span></td>
     <td class="" cellnumber="10" row="1" col="4"><span>10</span></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="" cellnumber="1" row="0" col="0"><span>1</span>
      <img src = "http://s23.postimg.org/ynlvim1x3/image.png" onclick="doSomething()"></td>
      <td class="" cellnumber="2" row="0" col="1"><span>2</span></td>
      <td class="" cellnumber="3" row="0" col="2"><span>3</span></td>
      <td class="" cellnumber="4" row="0" col="3"><span>4</span></td>
      <td class="" cellnumber="5" row="0" col="4"><span>5</span></td>
    </tr>
     </table>      
<script>
var canvas = document.getElementById('myCanvas');
  var context = canvas.getContext('2d');
  var imageObj = new Image();

      imageObj.onload = function() {
        context.drawImage(imageObj, 120, 50);
      };
      imageObj.src = 'http://s28.postimg.org/7sjqjzpah/ladderpattern.png';

      context.beginPath();
      context.moveTo(120, 45);
      context.lineTo(350, 150);
      context.stroke();
      context.stroke();

function doSomething()
{
    alert("Ping");
}
```

Comment: That won't be an easy one. But I think you could look for ladder vector, basically it will give you the "formula" to draw a ladder, then just try to translate it to JavaScript and it should work. Please let us know :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**You can use canvas' transformations to draw your angled ladder:**

- save the unrotated context state: `context.save();`
- translate to the beginning of your line: `context.translate(x,y);`.
- rotate to the same angle as your line: `context.rotate(lineAngle);`
- Translate resets the 0,0 origin at the specified x,y.  Rotate will rotate the entire canvas by the specified angle with the rotation point at the x,y you specified in Translate. By using translate and rotate, you don't have to recalculate the coordinates of code that draws your ladder for each new line.
- draw your ladder.
- restore the context to its unrotated state: `context.restore();`

[image]

Here's example code and a Demo:

```js
var canvas=document.getElementById("canvas");
var ctx=canvas.getContext("2d");

drawLadder(25,25,150,125);

function drawLadder(x0,y0,x1,y1){
  var dx=x1-x0;
  var dy=y1-y0;
  
  // calc the length of the line
  var length=Math.sqrt(dx*dx+dy*dy);
  
  // calc the angle of the line
  var angle=Math.atan2(dy,dx);

  // draw the ladder
  ctx.save();
  ctx.translate(x0,y0);
  ctx.rotate(angle);
  ctx.beginPath();
  ctx.moveTo(0,0);
  ctx.lineTo(length,0);
  ctx.moveTo(0,8);
  ctx.lineTo(length,8);
  for(var i=1;i<(length-2)/4;i++){
    ctx.moveTo(i*4,0);
    ctx.lineTo(i*4,8);
  }
  ctx.stroke();
  ctx.restore();

}
```

```css
body{ background-color: ivory; }
canvas{border:1px solid red;}
```

```html
<canvas id="canvas" width=300 height=300></canvas>
```